# Why does Entity Framework fail to query this table because of Boolean and Int data type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to query Customer Table which has a **Boolean** property called **"IsSubscribedToNewsletter"**. I did some changes in SQL Server and now I have problem **between data type Int and Boolean**. The data is sent from the form a **checkbox** which should be **Boolean** type **(IsSubscribedToNewsletter)**. I have no Idea what did I change that has caused data type issue?

**This is the query error:**

[image]

**and this is Customer Model:**

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(240)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsSubscribedToNewsletter { get; set; }

    public MembershipType MemberShipType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Membership")]
    public int MemberShipTypeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

**and this is the table in SQL Server:**

[image]

Comment: well, `int` is `int` ... `bit` is `bool` (sql type / C# type)

Comment: @Selvin oh yeah this is the mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your database table, you must change the datatype ***int*** to ***bit*** for IsSubscribedToNewsletter column.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a boolean property stored in a SQL Server database, the datatype of that column should be `bit`. While that looks like a number, the only possible values can be `1` or `0`.

The error that Entity Framework is throwing is because your C# property can only have 2 values, but in the database there can be the entire range of int32 numbers. It's guarding against a time when more than those two values are stored in that column.